# ADB push command android emulator

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, sl4a

I am trying to import a python library into SL4A. From my understanding, the easiest way to do this is to import the zipped files (egg files) of the python library into the SD Card and then import it into SL4A. Since I do not have an android device yet, I am working with the emulator. Whenever I try to push the zipped folder using the `adb push` command, it pops out an error saying the device is not connected. How do I push zipped files into the SD Card of an emulator and then access it via SL4A ? I want to use the commands in that library in the command line in SL4A.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own sdcard image, put files on it and after that mount in emulator.

To create image you can use `mksdcard <size> <file>`: `mksdcard 1024M sdcard1.iso`. After that you need to mount sdcard: `mount -o loop sdcard1.iso /mnt/cdrom/`. Next step: copy files, `umount /mnt/cdrom/` and point to image in virtual machine properties.

Comment: I have already created an sd card image. I downloaded and ran the SL4A on it. I dont want to make a new image now...How do I add files to an existing image ?

Comment: If you created image as described above you can mount it: `mount -o loop sdcard1.iso /mnt/cdrom/` and just copy files.